# Signature length not correct when calling PGPOnePassSignature.verify

Tags: java, cryptography, bouncycastle, gnupg

We’re using a Java libarary called [`license3j`](https://github.com/verhas/License3j) for license management. The library uses asymmetric encryption and relies itself on Bouncycastle. We create a license file using a simple `gpg` command and verify the license within our software using our public key. So far everything worked fine. BUT: In 1,000 generated licenses, there is a very small fraction which cannot be verified correctly, although, they are in fact valid (approximately 5/1000).

What happens in this case: When the license is to be verified in [`com.verhas.licensor.License.setLicenseEncoded(InputStream)`](https://github.com/verhas/License3j/blob/master/src/main/java/com/verhas/licensor/License.java#L732), the [`org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPOnePassSignature.verify(PGPSignature)`](https://github.com/verhas/License3j/blob/master/src/main/java/com/verhas/licensor/License.java#L775) throws the following exception:

`org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPRuntimeOperationException: unable to verify signature: Signature length not correct: got 511 but was expecting 512`

Sounds rather obscure to me, having only basic cryptography knowledge. Spending hours googling, gave me the clue, that there is something about "leading zeros". So, in the given example, obviously a leading zero was stripped away somewhere (where?), and the lengths of the signature data to compare do not match. Makes sense.

Now, I’ve no clue, where the issue might be located. Is it during **creation** of the license file? Essentially, we’re just doing the following:

```
gpg --armor --local-user=name.of.software --sign
```

Which will give us the license file.

Or does the error happen during **verification**? Do I have to modify any Bouncycastle configuration to correctly address the leading zero issue? Their [FAQ](http://www.bouncycastle.org/wiki/display/JA1/Frequently+Asked+Questions#FrequentlyAskedQuestions-4.WhenIencryptsomethingwithRSAIamlosingleadingzerobytesoffmydata,whyareyouguysshippingsuchabrokenimplementation?) gives some hints, but the `License3j` [source](https://github.com/verhas/License3j/blob/master/src/main/java/com/verhas/licensor/License.java#L732) obviously never makes use of any `Cipher` instance, so I’m totally lost on how to integrate this into the given API.

I’m aware that this is a very special problem with a library which is obviously not very well known. Thus, I appreciate any little feedback or input.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like it is a bug in bouncycastle, only encountered in versions of Java after 1.6, bouncycastle has always **created** the data wrong, but Java became more strict since 1.7 in the data it will accept during **verification**.

Bouncycastle is failing to pad the signature to the right length when it serializes it to the file, if the integer has enough leading zeros then the byte representation of it will be smaller.
Java versions 1.7 and above expect RSA signature bytes to be the same length as the key.

Bouncycastle converts the RSA signature byte array(returned from Java's RSA JCE provider) into an integer and it discards information about its length.
[Line 263 of the `PGPSignatureGenerator`](https://github.com/bcgit/bc-java/blob/master/pg/src/main/java/org/bouncycastle/openpgp/PGPSignatureGenerator.java#L263) shows where the RSA signature bytes are returned from JCE and converted into an integer.

This integer is eventually written to the outputstream using [`MPInteger#encode`](https://github.com/bcgit/bc-java/blob/master/pg/src/main/java/org/bouncycastle/bcpg/MPInteger.java#L42) which just uses the bitlength of the underlying biginteger to determine how much data to write.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40343731/1544715) describes more about why you see this aproximatley one in every 200 cases and how the version of Java plays a role.

Comment: Thank you Magnus, that really helped on understanding the issue! Do you have any suggestions how I could solve this problem with a manageable effort? Stepping through the BC source doesn't reveal any point where I could hook into. Are there any alternatives which I could use?

Comment: Unfortunately, fixing it in bouncycastle looks to be non-trivial, you could try raising a bug in their issue tracker but im not sure how much success you will have. A hacky work around could be to try and verify each license and regenerate it if it fails.

Comment: Actually I also had the idea with regenerating the licenses, but our server where the licenses are generated is not running in a Java environment. It would be a huge pita to set up a JRE just for verifying the licenses. I'll try to raise an issue at BC about it. One more question: Are there further crypto libraries beside BC, or can the verification of a GPG signature also be performed with classes from the Java API nowadays? After all, there is e.g. a `java.security.Signature` class. The verification steps do not seem too complicated at all, so I'd also consider re-writing that functionality.

Comment: I don't believe there are any other free Java libraries that do PGP. 
The actual RSA signature verification is being processed by the Java standard library, which is why the behavior changed in 1.7. If you want to modify license3j, you might be able to hack in some padding by wrapping the verifier provider, but im not sure if it will work. https://gist.github.com/magJ/27b2909ce749da6dd0ea19a3eb334a53

Comment: Cool, I'll check this out once I find some more free minutes! Thank you!!